# Присвоил кнопке обработчик событий on_release: webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.google.com") при нажатии на кнопку выходит ошибка NameError

Tags: python, kivy

Импортировал все нужные модули включая webbrowser
[image: мой код]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.